# Sorting list of object by object types in Java

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have 2 Objects:

```
public class GroupObject
{
  String name;
  ...
}

public class AddressObject
{
  String name;
  ...
}
```

I have a collection of them both:

```
List<Object> _listValues;
```

Before I start working on ***_listValues*** I need to sort objects:

1. All GroupObjects should be top of the list, AddressObjects should come after GroupObjects
2. Inside of this order, GroupObjects must be sorted by *name* property, as well as AddressObjects.

It looks like this now:

> _listValues[0] --> AddressObject "c-address"
>
> _listValues[1] --> AddressObject "b-address"
>
> _listValues[2] --> GroupObject "b-group"
>
> _listValues[3] --> AddressObject "a-address"
>
> _listValues[4] --> GroupObject "a-group"
>
> _listValues[5] --> AddressObject "d-address"

It should look like this:

> _listValues[0] --> GroupObject "a-group"
>
> _listValues[1] --> GroupObject "b-group"
>
> _listValues[2] --> AddressObject "a-address"
>
> _listValues[3] --> AddressObject "b-address"
>
> _listValues[4] --> AddressObject "c-address"
>
> _listValues[5] --> AddressObject "d-address"

How can I sort the ***_listValues*** in order to achieve that?

Comment: Create a custom comparator and use build-in sort method. Alternatively you could write your own sorting method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by splitting into smaller lists, sorting and concating again. This can help for more complex collections too.

Also you can choose which object should be on top of the list too.

```
    private List<Object> sortValuesList(List<Object> listValues)
    {
        List<Object> listObject = new ArrayList<>();
        List<GroupObject> listGroups = new ArrayList<>();
        List<AddressObject> listAddress = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object obj : listValues)
        {
            if (obj instanceof GroupObject)
            {
               listGroups.add((GroupObject) obj);
            }
            else if (obj instanceof AddressObject)
            {
                listAddress.add((AddressObject) obj);
            }
        }

        listGroups.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.name.compareTo(o2.name));
        listAddress.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.name.compareTo(o2.name));

        listObject = Stream.concat(listGroups.stream(), listAddress.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return listObject;
    }
```

Comment: Nice but how to order desc?

Comment: listGroups.sort((o1, o2) -> o1.name.compareTo(o2.name), Collections.reverseOrder()); you can use it like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List#sort`:

```
     _listValues.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1 instanceof GroupObject && o2 instanceof AddressObject) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o1 instanceof AddressObject && o2 instanceof GroupObject) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o1 instanceof GroupObject && o2 instanceof GroupObject) {
            GroupObject g1 = (GroupObject) o1;
            GroupObject g2 = (GroupObject) o2;
            return g1.getName().compareTo(g2.getName());
        } else {
            AddressObject a1 = (AddressObject) o1;
            AddressObject a2 = (AddressObject) o2;
            return a1.getName().compareTo(a2.getName());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you. It helped in a way but doesn't necessarily put the GroupObject on top of the list, if the first object of unsorted list is not a GroupObject. I've posted a bit 'heavier' answer.

Answer (score 0):

A more robust solution could be to let the classes implement some common interface, let's call it `Sortable`:

```
public interface Sortable {
  String getName();
  int getSortOrder();
}
```

Your classes would then look something like this:

```
public class GroupObject implements Sortable {
  String name;

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Override
  public int getSortOrder() {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

And the sorting would be as simple as:

```
_listValues.sort(Comparator.comparing(Sortable::getSortOrder).thenComparing(Sortable::getName));
```

Given that `_listValues` is of type `List<Sortable>`.